# Seeking open raw LiDAR or laser scanner data?

Tags: data, lidar, las, europe, ftp

I'm looking for aerial LiDAR or terrestrial laser scanner data in laz or las format preferably from an FTP site.

Does anyone know which countries have that data available to the public?

From my research it doesn't seem to be easy to come by.