# Digital Surface Model data for Switzerland?

Tags: data, dem, lidar, switzerland

I'd like to get Digital Surface Model data from Switzerland. I want to calculate building volume from it. Even I am searching for LIDAR data, but I did not find any free data.

Is there any free LiDAR or DSM data set available for this country?

Comment: Completely don't agree in that this is a duplicate, since this user needs digital elevation data in a resolution suitable to calculate building volumes (laserscan, sub-meter), and the data referred to in the referenced question is roundabout 30m resolution and has not the required accuracy in height.

Comment: I specifically mentioned i want Digital Surface Data for only Switzerland. There are many services who provides data of UK and Germany. Here i Need only Switzerland Data which contains Height of Surfaces. so This questions should not be duplicate. Duplicated question is completely different than this

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179335/where-can-i-find-open-raw-lidar-or-laser-scanner-data. https://maps.zh.ch

Comment: Following the comment from @AndreSilva I have changed the duplicate.  If none of the answers to the duplicate question provide you a solution please [edit] your question to describe in more detail why not.